# Django unit test. Simple example

Tags: python, django, testcase, django-testing

I learn unit test with Django. How to write test for this function? I need this example to understand.

```
@login_required
def datas(request):
    queryset = Data.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if queryset.count() == 0:
        return redirect('/data/')
    return render_to_response('data_list.html',
                              {'data': queryset},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far. Post your code and tell us what error's you're getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#imports here

class YourTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['user-data.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_empty_datas(self):
        self.client.login(username='something', password='something')
        response = self.client.get('/path/to/view/')  # or reverse by name
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302,
            'View did not redirect on empty queryset.')

    def test_populated_datas(self):
        self.client.login(username='something', password='something')
        Data.objects.create(some_field=some_value)
        response = self.client.get('/path/to/view/')  # or reverse by name
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200,
            'View did not return a 200.')
```

...and so on. user-data would need to contain at least one user, otherwise you won't be able to authenticate.